# storing Multiple selected radiobutton's of gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have gridview which contains 60 rows and each row has 4 radiobutton option (select any one). To opearate that code , on submit button wrote code as follows . I didn't work.
My design view :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSurvey" runat="server" CellPadding = "4"  OnRowDataBound ="gvSurvey_RowDataBound" BorderWidth ="2"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No data Available" GridLines="None"
HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="#333333" Font-Names="Verdana" ShowFooter="True">
<RowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="HEADER" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="QTN_NO" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="SQTN_NO" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" >
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:BoundField>
<asp:TemplateField Visible="true" HeaderText ="Strongly Disagree">
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:RadioButton ID="rdbtn1" runat ="server" GroupName ="MyRadioGroup"/>
<%-- <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvRadioButtonGroup" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* make a selection" onservervalidate="cvRadioButtonGroup_ServerValidate" /> --%>
  <%--<input name="MyRadioButton1" type ="radio" value = "'<%# Eval("SQTN_NO") %>'" />--%>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField Visible="true" HeaderText ="Agree">
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbtn2" runat ="server"  GroupName ="MyRadioGroup"/>
  <%--<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvRadioButtonGroup" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* make a selection" onservervalidate="cvRadioButtonGroup_ServerValidate" /> --%>
 <%--<input name="MyRadioButton2" type ="radio" value = "'<%# Eval("SQTN_NO") %>'" />--%>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField Visible="true" HeaderText ="Disagree">
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbtn3" runat ="server" GroupName ="MyRadioGroup"/>
  <%-- <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvRadioButtonGroup" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* make a selection" onservervalidate="cvRadioButtonGroup_ServerValidate" /> --%>
  <%--<input name="MyRadioButton3" type ="radio" value = "'<%# Eval("SQTN_NO") %>'" />--%>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField Visible="true" HeaderText ="Strongly Agree">
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbtn4" runat ="server"  GroupName ="MyRadioGroup"/>
      <%--  <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvRadioButtonGroup" runat="server" ErrorMessage="* make a selection" onservervalidate="cvRadioButtonGroup_ServerValidate" /> --%>
<%-- <input name="MyRadioButton4" type ="radio" value = "'<%# Eval("SQTN_NO") %>'" />--%>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

</asp:GridView>
```

C#

```
 for (i = 0; i < gvSurvey.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                RadioButton rdbtn1 = (RadioButton)gvSurvey.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("rdbtn1");
                RadioButton rdbtn2 = (RadioButton)gvSurvey.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("rdbtn2");
                RadioButton rdbtn3 = (RadioButton)gvSurvey.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("rdbtn3");
                RadioButton rdbtn4 = (RadioButton)gvSurvey.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("rdbtn4");


          //      RadioButton rdbtn1=(RadioButton) gvSurvey.Rows[i].ClientID  

                qtn_no = dtSurvey.Rows[i]["QTN_NO"].ToString();
                sqtn_no = dtSurvey.Rows[i]["SQTN_NO"].ToString();

                if (rdbtn1.Checked)
                {
                    rdbtn1.Text = "1";
                    lblMsg.Text = nominationsBiz.SaveSuggestion(ticketNo.ToString(), qtn_no, sqtn_no, rdbtn1.Text);
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Go through the following code you will find the Solutions

```
 //  It will be on your submit button click 
    protected void getPinCode()
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow grdRows in gvSurvey.Rows)
        {
            RadioButton rbt1 = (RadioButton)grdRows.FindControl("rdbtn1");
            RadioButton rbt2 = (RadioButton)grdRows.FindControl("rdbtn2");
            RadioButton rbt3 = (RadioButton)grdRows.FindControl("rdbtn3");
            RadioButton rbt4 = (RadioButton)grdRows.FindControl("rdbtn4");

            string Value = RadioValue(rbt1);
           //Similarly you can do for all radio button 
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value))
            {

                lblMsg.Text = nominationsBiz.SaveSuggestion(ticketNo.ToString(), qtn_no, sqtn_no, Value);
            }

        }
    }


    protected string RadioValue(RadioButton Rbtlst)
    {
        string Value = "";

        if (Rbtlst.Checked == true)
        {
            Value = Rbtlst.Text;
        }
        return Value;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply ... I tried it in your way but it didn't work .

I get the control radiobutton but its property are not set as on the page (like it shows {checked=False} Though its value has changed on page )

Comment: i din`t get you what actually you want? do you want to change the text of the radio button or you want to get the only text of the radio button.First you have to care about the code from which you binding the grid must be in side the if(!ispost) method

Comment: Really thanks !!  if (!IsPostBack) Solved my problem..Thanks once again